dblclick, onmouseover events not working for me ( i am using chrome)


const b = document.querySelector('#but');

b.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
  console.log('dblclick');
});

b.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  console.log('mouseenter');
});

b.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  console.log('mouseleave');
});
<button id="but">Button</button>



Events Not Working: The dblclick, onmouseover, and onmouseenter events do not fire as expected.
I've tried attaching these events to elements like buttons and headings using both addEventListener and inline event handlers (ondblclick, onmouseover, onmouseenter).
dblclick: Doesn't trigger the event handler on double-click.
onmouseover and onmouseenter: Do not respond when hovering over elements, but clicking works fine.

I created a demo snippet from the JS you provided, assuming that #but is a button element. It works absolutely fine here. We need more context about your HTML to understand what's happening. Also, if #but is a button element, then check if it's submitting a form when you click it (although this shouldn't stop the mouse events from working). Also ensure that the #but element exist at the point that you call addEventListener() and isn't added to the DOM after the page loads.

You could try to change:
const b = document.querySelector('#but');

To:
const b = document.getElementById('but');

Also, have you checked the console for any errors? Maybe your JS is loading faster than your dom (?).
Another thing you can do is adding an eventListener for DOMContentLoaded on document. That would result in the following:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log("content loaded");

  const b = document.querySelector('#but');

  b.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
      console.log('hey');
  });
});



<button id="but">Click me bro</button>


<script src="app.js"></script>


This is my HTML code. I didn't see any errors in my console. I made the changes as you suggested, but it still did not work for me. But i tried it in Microsoft edge browser it works. i don't know what is the problem in my google browser  .Thanks for your response to my question.
